# Load GridView in ASP.NET using C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I tried loading a DataGridView with data from server and the code I wrote is saying the data source is null during debugging.

```
protected void ViewData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var files = new DBEntitiesModelConn())
    {
        var ViewData= from i in files.LicenseApplicationCPs
                              select new
                                  {
                                      Name = i.Name,
                                      Status = i.Status,
                                      Date = i.DateSubmitted,
                                  };
        ViewDataGrid.DataSource = ViewData.ToList();
    }
}
```

The datasource is saying is null.

Comment: i am not sure if typo or not, but you are loading/listing `ViewData` not `ViewApplication`

Comment: I edited the code. @Gabriel Llorico

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net, it's often important to have certain data available and ready at certain points in the page life cycle, and not before.  For example, you may need to bind to a drop down list early to allow setting the selected index on that list later. Or you might want to wait a bit to bind that large grid to reduce the amount of time you hold that connection active/keep the data in memory.

Having you explicitly call the `.DataBind()` method makes it possible to support scenarios at both ends of the spectrum.

```
protected void ViewData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var files = new DBEntitiesModelConn())
    {
        var ViewData= from i in files.LicenseApplicationCPs
                              select new
                                  {
                                      Name = i.Name,
                                      Status = i.Status,
                                      Date = i.DateSubmitted,
                                  };
        ViewDataGrid.DataSource = ViewData.ToList();
        ViewDataGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems hat the error still persists on  ViewDataGrid.DataSource = ViewData.ToList();

Comment: Do you find any values on `ViewData.ToList()` ?

Comment: Its saying null and inside the ViewData there is this error which says  (Sql The function evaluation requires all threads to run)